# How to split string of multiple lists into individual lists?

Tags: python, python-2.6

After trying the reply below it seems my lists are not a string but a bunch of lists separated by "\n" because when I try to replace the quotes with triple quotes I get an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'. So to change my question, how do I get individual lists from the following which is apparently not a string?

```
x = [u'Tonight']
[u'Partly', u'cloudy.', u'Clearing', u'this', u'evening.', u'Wind',     u'west', u'20', u'km/h', u'gusting', u'to', u'40', u'becoming', u'light',     u'this', u'evening.', u'Low', u'9.']
[u'31', u'Aug']
[u'Increasing', u'cloudiness', u'near', u'noon.', u'Wind', u'becoming',     u'southwest', u'30', u'km/h', u'early', u'in', u'the', u'afternoon.',     u'High', u'19.', u'UV', u'index', u'4', u'or', u'moderate.']
[u'Night']
[u'Clearing', u'in', u'the', u'evening.', u'Wind', u'southwest', u'30',     u'km/h', u'becoming', u'light', u'in', u'the', u'evening.', u'Low', u'8.']
[u'1', u'Sep']
[u'Sunny.', u'High', u'22.']
[u'Night']
[u'Clear.', u'Low', u'10.']
[u'2', u'Sep']
[u'Sunny.', u'High', u'15.']
[u'Night']
[u'Clear.', u'Low', u'plus', u'3.']
[u'3', u'Sep']
[u'Cloudy', u'with', u'40', u'percent', u'chance', u'of', u'showers.',     u'High', u'12.']
[u'Night']
[u'Cloudy', u'with', u'30', u'percent', u'chance', u'of', u'showers.',     u'Low', u'plus', u'4.']
[u'4', u'Sep']
[u'Cloudy', u'with', u'30', u'percent', u'chance', u'of', u'showers.',     u'High', u'12.']
[u'Night']
[u'Cloudy', u'with', u'60', u'percent', u'chance', u'of', u'showers.',     u'Low', u'plus', u'4.']
[u'5', u'Sep']
[u'Cloudy', u'with', u'60', u'percent', u'chance', u'of', u'showers.',     u'High', u'12.']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = """..."""
>>> [ast.literal_eval(l) for l in x.split('\n')]
[[u'Tonight'], [u'Partly', u'cloudy.', u'Clearing', u'this', u'evening.', u'Wind', u'west', u'20', u'km/h', u'gusting', u'to', u'40', u'becoming', u'light', u'this', u'evening.', u'Low', u'9.'], [u'31', u'Aug'], [u'Increasing', u'cloudiness', u'near', u'noon.', u'Wind', u'becoming', u'southwest', u'30', u'km/h', u'early', u'in', u'the', u'afternoon.', u'High', u'19.', u'UV', u'index', u'4', u'or', u'moderate.'],...]
```

Make sure to surround the string in triple quotes.